# How to add text to Table header dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add text to table header's dynamically but I can't think of anything.

This is how I add text to div,

```
var textForDiv1 = getFromArray.ResourceKey;
$("#someDIVId").text(textForDiv1);
```

and it works, but how can I do same for a `<th>` ?

**Edit**

Html is being added dynamically, but this is how I am adding th

```
    var someRow= "<tr class='someClass' ><th>text1</th><th>text2</th></tr>"; // add resources
    $("#Table").append(someRow);
```

Comment: show your html and what is expected output

Comment: So, which `th` you want to put some text in?

Comment: @abhitalks yup, that's right

Comment: I asked, *which* `th` you want to put your text in?

Comment: @abhitalks obviously both of them :S

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/M6VEL/

Comment: @CustomizedName: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/CYVH4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give your headers an id when creating them and just access them as you would any other element:

```
$(function(){
 var someRow= "<tr class='someClass' ><th id='header1' >text1</th><th>text2</th></tr>"; // add resources
    $("#Table").append(someRow);

    $("#header1").text("Banana");
});
```

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/M6VEL/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

You can select th elements much in the same way that you can select other elements on the page (like divs) using any valid CSS selector. For example if you wanted to dynamically change the table headers for this table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>One</th>
    <th id='th-two'>Two</th>
    <th class='tablehead'>Three</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You could do something like this:

```
<script>
 // change the first table header
 var newTableHeader = 'Five';
 $('table th').eq(0).text( newTableHeader );

 // change the second table header
 var newTableHeader = 'Four';
 $('th#th-two').text( newTableHeader );

 // change the third table header
 var newTableHeader = 'Six';
 $('.tablehead').text( newTableHeader );
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set on all `th` of table some text then do like this:

```
    $("#Table th").each(function () {

     $(this).text("Dummy text")
 })
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/ePqhs/)

for dynamic and different content in each `th` you can do:

```
var temp = new Array();

temp.push("text1");
temp.push("text2");
var i =0;
 $("#Table th").each(function () {

     $(this).text(temp[i])
     i++;
 })
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/ZWmH4/)

Comment: Thank you, but each table header will have different text

Comment: you can put whatever text is needed

Answer (score 0):

You can identify each `th` by its unique `id` if you have them.

As I can see from your example, `id`s aren't there. So, you need to target them using `nth-child` selector.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/CYVH4/1/***

*Relevant JS*:

```
$("#tab").find("tr.someClass").first().children("th:nth-child(1)").text("Header One");

$("#tab").find("tr.someClass").first().children("th:nth-child(2)").text("Header Two");
```

So, you use `nth-child(n)` to target the cells you are after. Alternatively, you could use jQuery `.eq(n)` to target a specific cell.

```
$("#tab tr.someClass").eq(0).children("th").eq(0).text("Header One");
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the `thead` in the selector.

```
<table id="Table">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>   
</table>
```

add `thead` in there with `#Table`

```
var someRow= "<tr class='someClass' ><th>text1</th><th>text2</th></tr>"; // add resources
$("#Table thead").append(someRow);
```